# Android 7.0 and above Javascript not working Webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am integrating payment gateway in my application using WebView. I want to read the response from HTML content basically it is a JSON object. This is working fine on 6.0 devices. But for 7.0 and 8.0 I am facing issue with JavaScript. I am using the below code.

My Code

```
    vPayment.loadUrl(myurl);

    wvPayment.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvPayment.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wvPayment.clearCache(true);
    wvPayment.clearHistory();
    wvPayment.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wvPayment.addJavascriptInterface(iface, "HTMLOUT");
    wvPayment.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    wvPayment.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (request.getUrl().toString().contains("mysuuccessurl")) {
                try {
                    String html = URLDecoder.decode(request.getUrl().toString(), "UTF-8").substring(9);
                    System.out.println("html" + html);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Log.e("example", "failed to decode source", e);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            System.out.println("Start url : " + url);
            customProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("Finish url : " + url);
            if (url.contains(mysuccessurl)) {
                wvPayment.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
            }
            customProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
JIFace iface = new JIFace();


class JIFace {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String data) {
       //want to handle the response here

        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the above code. What changes needs for this work on 7.0 and above android devices

Comment: change window.HTMLOUT to HTMLOUT

Comment: Same issue JavaScript is currently disabled or is not supported by your browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Android doc

This is pre Android N

```
@Deprecated
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return false;
}
```

This is since Android N

@return True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView
        and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return true;
    }
```

This method is from Android N , so for this reason you have this issue only in Android N. Returning false you should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone also stumbling upon this I've found that android versions below 7 allow ".cshtml" files to be rendered but from android 7 nougart onwards (7.0,7.1,8.0,8.1 etc...) will only output their source code.

I was using some cshtml files generated by a asp.net project and I'd copied the files out of that project and into my xamarin project.

Changing the extension of the files to .html fixed it for me. :)